# Finding the minimum value of the maximum cluster?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures, stream, cluster-analysis

Define an item as having:

- a unique id
- a value
- a creation time
- a deletion time

I have two input streams - one that informs me when an item is created, one that informs me when the item is deleted.  Call an item that has been created but not destroyed "living."

I can track the maximum value of all living items using a heap:

```
whenCreated(item):
  i = heap.size
  heap-up(item, heap.size)
  heap.size = heap.size + 1
  max-value = heap[0]

whenDeleted(item):
  ktem = heap[heap.size - 1]
  heap.size = heap.size - 1
  heap-up(ktem, index[item.id])
  heap-down(ktem, index[ktem.id])
  max-value = heap[0]

heap-up(item, i):
  while (i > 0):
    j = floor( (i-1) / 2 )
    jtem = heap[j]
    if (jtem.value > item.value):
      break while
    index[jtem.id] = i 
    heap[i] = heap[i]
    i = j
  index[item.id] = i
  heap[i] = item

heap-down(item, i):
  while (2*i + 1 < heap.size):
    if (2*i + 1 == heap.size or heap[2*i+1].value > heap[2*i+2].value):
      j = 2*i + 1
    else
      j = 2*i + 2          
    jtem = heap[j]
    if (jtem.value < item.value):
      break while
    index[jtem.id] = i
    heap[i] = heap[i] 
    i = j         
  index[item.id] = i
  heap[i] = item
```

If I've got `n` items, then adding or deleting one takes `O(log n)` time.

Now suppose the items are clustered such that given two items, `a` and `b`, `|a.value - b.value| < delta` ⇒ `a` and `b` are in the same cluster.

For example, if we've got the values `(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16)` and `delta = 2`, then the clusters are `(1, 2, 3, 4)`, `(7, 8)`, `(11)`, and `(13, 14, 15, 16)`.

I'd like to track the minimum value of the cluster that contains the maximum living value.  I can do this by reading values off the heap in order until I find a gap between values of size greater than equal to `delta`.  However, this takes `O(n)` time, which seems rather inefficent.

Is there an `O(log n)` algorithm to track the minimum value of that cluster?

Comment: Are clusters transitive?  For example, if the delta is 2, are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 all in the same cluster?

Comment: I doubt you can do it with only your current heap. It seems you'll need a separate data structure to do this efficiently. A disjoint set would be good, although your clusters can merge and then unmerge, so you need something that allows separation (which union-find doesn't), aka partition refinement.

Comment: templatetypedef's answer works, although it seems a difficult implementation. If you don't anticipate many borderline cases then maybe the simple `O(n)` solution is worthwhile. Meaning if it will be rare that the end of the cluster changes often then it's not the end of the world. You can improve it slightly by moving to a BST and maintaining a single pointer, and then your `O(n)` work doesn't happen on delete, only on inserts and even then, if you expect small clusters relative to `n` it shouldn't be noticeable.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can do this using a balanced binary search tree of splay trees to guarantee O(log n) amortized time for each operation.

Suppose that we weren't doing any clustering.  In that case, you could just store all the elements in a balanced binary search tree to get O(log n) insertion, deletion, and find-min.  But with clustering, this changes.  My suggestion is to maintain a BST of the clusters sorted by the range of values held in the cluster, where each cluster is represented as a splay tree of the nodes it contains.

To insert an element into the data structure, do a search in the BST for the predecessor and successor of the element in question.  If the node belongs to neither of these clusters, create a singleton splay tree out of that node and insert it into the BST.  If it's contained in exactly one of the two clusters you found, insert it into that cluster.  If it's contained in both clusters, then remove both clusters from the BST, merge them together into one cluster, insert the new node into that cluster, then reinsert the cluster into the BST.  The lookup time in all cases in O(log n) to find the two clusters, then O(log n) amortized time to insert into a cluster.  Merging two splay trees is actually fast here; since he clusters were not merged before, one tree holds values that are all strictly greater than all the values in the other tree, so the merge can be done in O(log n) amortized time by retiring pointers.  The cost of removing the two trees and adding them back in is also O(log n).

To find the minimum value of the maximum cluster, find the maximum cluster in the BST in O(log n) time, then find the minimum element of the cluster you find in amortized O(log n) time.

To delete an element, find the cluster that contains it in O(log n) time.  If it is in its own cluster, delete that cluster Fromm the tree.  If not, remove the element from the cluster it's in, then find its predecessor and successor within that cluster.  If they are within delta of one another, then the cluster is still fine and we are done.  Otherwise, the cluster must be split.  In O(log n) amortized time, split the cluster into the cluster of nodes less than or equal to the predecessor and greater or equal to the successor, then reinsert both clusters into the tree.

Overall, this gives O(log n) amortized for each operation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary trees (or its variants) instead of heaps. Finding a value and minimum value are both in O(logn). Construct separate binary trees for each cluster.

I am not sure how the clustering is done (you can construct multiple clustering that satisfy the delta condition you mention. Why did you choose this particular clustering?). You can also consider having one giant binary search tree to store all the values and designate some of the nodes as "cluster heads" (i.e. The elements in the sub-tree containing this node is a cluster). This way, you should easily be able to create and delete new clusters.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this helps when you factor in clustering.  How would you determine efficiently whether two nodes are in the same cluster?

Comment: What happens if you need to merge two clusters?  Or split a cluster in two?

Comment: @templatetypedef Create separate tree for each cluster.

Comment: @templatetypedef Why would you want to merge or split? Not mentioned in the problem. Anyways, splitting is easy: just split the tree! If each of the clusters' range is separate (i.e. all elements in one cluster are greater than every element in the second cluster), then merging should also be very simple.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting the problem, but if you have two groups of nodes that are clustered together and you add in a new value in-between them, I think that this results in the two clusters merging into one single cluster.  Similarly, deleting a node from a cluster might split the cluster into two.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @templatetypedef Now I am confused too! If you go strictly by this definition "a and b, |a.value - b.value| < delta ⇒ a and b are in the same cluster" then you can construct many clusterings with same data.

Comment: Clusters are dynamic, in fact on repeated insert and delete operations they can merge and unmerge, for example `delta=2, {1,2,3},{5,6,7} add(4), delete(4), add(4), ...` will result in those clusters merging and unmerging, which would take `O(n)` worst case if you have to merge separate trees. Indeed merging is easy, but unmerging isn't so easy, what if the example were slightly more complicated, e.g. `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, delete(3), add(3), delete(4), add(4), ...` every split requires a tree restructure in `O(n)`.

Comment: @davin Why do you "must" split when delete an element? Eg: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, delete(3) . Could you tell more about it in the problem definition.

Comment: @ElKamina, you have a set of elements that used to be a cluster and were therefore in one tree, but no longer fulfils the requirements of a cluster (once you delete 3, the elements 2 and 4 have a distance that is *not* strictly less than 2), so the tree must be split into two.

Comment: @davin Got it! In that case you should refine the question, especially the criteria. It should read something like: For every element a in cluster there exists at least one b such that a!=b and |a-b|<=delta

Comment: @ElKamina, I didn't write the question, so I'm not going to refine it. Moreover, the question is defined adequately IMO.

Comment: @davin One more question. When you add a new value, is it always going to be added at the ends of a cluster? For example if you cluster is {4,5,6}, is it the case that you always add 3 or 7, but never 4.5?

Comment: @ElKamina: Nope, the value of an item has nothing to do with its creation or deletion time.